# WCF - The client and > service bindings may be mismatched

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Error:

> Content Type multipart/related;
>   type="application/xop+xml";start="http://tempuri.org/0";boundary="uuid:ba0ec7a3-1707-44b9-be72-2fe11d4dfe2b+id=4";start-info="text/xml"
>   was not supported by service
>   `http://ServerName/FolderName/ServiceName.svc.`  The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched.

Client Config :

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1371/Service.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="Service.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Server Config :

```
<bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>         
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
             <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
             <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
             </security>
          </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: try copy service binding to client

Comment: copy tag `bindings` from server config to client config

Comment: i got another exception `The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Have you browsed to the WSDL on your endpoint - one of the errors says: "text/xml" was not supported by service - so maybe the endpoint isn't actually serving or is incorrectly specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `messageEncoding` bit from your `basicHttpBinding` binding. It's currently set to "MTOM" which doesnt allow *text/xml* transmission.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.messageencoding.aspx).